# Unable to build Adhoc distribution from command line

Tags: appcelerator

I am trying to script the IPA creation process for Appcelarator Alloy project with `grunt` using the `grunt-appc-cli` plugin.

My target config looks like below:

```
'dist-prod': {
                'command': "run",
                'args': [ 
                    '-p', 'ios',
                    '-T', 'dist-adhoc',
                    '-R', '<Dev Cert Name>',
                    '-P', '<Provisioning Profile UUID>',
                    '-O', './dist/prod/',
                    '--log-level', 'trace'
                ]
            },
```

Running this grunt target gets stuck at following:

```
>> [INFO]  JavaScript files need to be encrypted
>> [INFO]  Creating Xcode project
>> [TRACE] Removing pre-compile phase
>> [TRACE] Adding 3 native module libraries
>> [TRACE] No extensions to add
>> [INFO]  Creating Entitlements.plist
>> [INFO]  Creating Info.plist
>> [INFO]  Disabling ATS
>> [INFO]  Creating main.m
>> [INFO]  Creating Xcode config files
>> [INFO]  Copying Titanium libraries
>> [INFO]  Copying Titanium iOS files
>> [TRACE] Skipping Classes/ApplicationRouting.m, it'll be processed later
```

After a while I have to `Ctrl+C` to kill without generating an IPA.

Any pointers to debug this issue?

**** More Info ****
I tried to run the `appc run` cmd directly and end up with the following error message:

`$ appc run -p ios -T dist-adhoc -R  "<Dev Cert Name>" -P "<Provisioning Profile UUID>" -O ../Svc --log-level trace`

```
[ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         CompileC build/Intermediates/FSM.build/Release-iphoneos/FSM.build/Objects-norm
al/armv7/TiUIiOSProxy.o Classes/TiUIiOSProxy.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] (1 failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running on Xcode 7.3.1 and above and Titanium SDK 5.4 GA - That should address your problem.

Check more details here - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23674

If you still see the problem with the above environment, please provide more details in the JIRA ticket.